# Cannot put string into array in PHP

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I try to put a string to `$qDateTime` and print it out.
I expect the result is `Array ( [0] => 2013-12-16 08:38:33 [1] => 2013-12-16 08:44:58 )`.
But it print `Array ( [0] => 2013 [1] => 2013 )`.
And the `$temp` can print out correctly like `2013-12-16 08:38:332013-12-16 08:44:58`.

```
    $qDateTime = array();

    $query = "SELECT joinDateTime FROM queueItem WHERE uid = '".$uid."' AND isValid = true;";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Fail");
    while($array = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $temp = $array['joinDateTime'];
        $qDateTime[] += $temp;
        echo $temp;

    }
    print_r($qDateTime);
```

Comment: Correct syntax for pushing into array is `$qDateTime[] = $temp;`

Comment: `$qDateTime[] = $temp`, not `+=`.

Answer (score 3):

```
    $temp = $array['joinDateTime'];
    $qDateTime[] += $temp;
    echo $temp;
```

You're assigning data to the array wrongly:

```
    $qDateTime[] += $temp;
```

Should be:

```
    $qDateTime[] = $temp;
```

Because you're using `+=` in your code, PHP is converting the date string to an integer, and using that for the result; so your `2013-12-16 08:38:332013-12-16` is becoming just `2013`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$qDateTime[] = $temp;` instead of `$qDateTime[] += $temp;`

```
    while($array = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $temp = $array['joinDateTime'];
        $qDateTime[] = $temp;
        echo $temp;

    }

    var_dump($qDateTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way of data assignment to array is incorrect. it should be,

```
$qDateTime[] = $temp; instead of $qDateTime[] += $temp;

print_r($qDateTime);
```

So the correct code must be,

```
  $qDateTime = array();

    $query = "SELECT joinDateTime FROM queueItem WHERE uid = '".$uid."' AND isValid = true;";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Fail");
    while($array = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $temp = $array['joinDateTime'];
        $qDateTime[] = $temp;
        echo $temp;

    }
    print_r($qDateTime);
```